# Connection error while integrating mlflow with zenml

Tags: mlflow

I've been trying to integrate mlflow with zenml. the following error keeps coming up, whenever i am trying to integrate

**ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))**

I've followed following to install the mlflow,
**zenml integration install mlflow -y**

but whenerver i run **zenml experiment-tracker register mlflow_tracker --flavor=mlflow**
to integrate, the following error keeps coming up,

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

I've tried zenml down and zenml up many times. still the error is coming

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, consider setting the environment variable: OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES. Depending on your chosen interpreter (such as .bashrc or .zshrc), add this variable to the respective configuration file